# Changing value of specific key changes the value of other keys as well

Tags: java, kotlin, arraylist, key-value

This is how I generate dutyList.

```
val dutyList = ArrayList<Triple<Int, String, ArrayList<Pair<String, String>>>>()

val dateShiftPair = ArrayList<Pair<String, String>>()

dateList.forEach {date ->
     dateShiftPair.add(Pair(date, "E"))
}


staffList.forEach {staff -> 
     dutyList.add(Triple(list.indexOf(staff), staff.name!!, dateShiftPair))
}
```

And this should change the second value of the pair

```
override fun onShiftChange(pos: Int, datePos: Int, shift: String) {
        val pair = Pair(staffList[pos].third[datePos].first, shift)
        staffListUpdated[pos].third[datePos] = pair
    }
```

but instead it changes other values in **pos**, that is if I change **staffListUpdated[0].third[0] = pair** it changes **staffListUpdated[1].third[0] = pair** as well. I tried many ways but nothing helped.

```
[
  {
    "first": 0,
    "second": "Ralph",
    "third": [
      {
        "first": "3/5",
        "second": "G" //change should happen here only
      },
      {
        "first": "4/5",
        "second": "E"
      },
      {
        "first": "6/5",
        "second": "E"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "first": 1,
    "second": "Mike",
    "third": [
      {
        "first": "3/5",
        "second": "G" //but change happens here as well.
      },
      {
        "first": "4/5",
        "second": "E"
      },
      {
        "first": "5/5",
        "second": "E"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: This does not compile

Comment: Probably because the equals method of Pair does not compare the key inside it when indexof is called on the list

Comment: But anyway, why won't you use a map (hashmap) instead of a list with pairs in it

Comment: Hashmaps are faster and you can easily use containsKey() to figure out of a key exists

Comment: Your code uses the same list instance as the third value for all triples.

Comment: @Ackdari you are right, maybe you should put that as the answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In

```
staffList.forEach {staff -> 
     dutyList.add(Triple(list.indexOf(staff), staff.name!!, dateShiftPair))
}
```

you use for every `Triple` the same list instance.

This means if you get the list of one of your `Triple`s and change something you change it for every `Triple`.

A solution is to copy the list either on insertion or on modification.

You also need to do a deep copy of the list. Because if you make a shallow copy of the list the instances of the `Pair`s are still the same and if you then change one of them you change it (again) for every `Triple`.